# Java cloud application for stock analysis

Tags: java

I have a java application deployed in Cloud. As application is reachable in cloud all the time, I want to use java variables(instead of DB) to store the values, update it every one minute using some API calls. Using **Threadmodel** in java. I want to fire 100 API's and update 100 Java variables every minute.

I am mostly worried about the performance of the application. Please let me know, if it is good approach to go ahead or any alternative to achieve above requirement.

UseCase: Stock market application where every minute will fire 100 APIs to get latest values of top stocks and analyze it.

Regards, Stocklearner.

Comment: Storing values in variables won't be a performance problem.  Making 100 API calls per minute might cause performance problems.  But that depends on the API calls themselves, load on the API servers, network congestion and so on.   There are too many "unknowns" to make predictions about possible problems.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). Implement it and then look how to optimize it. Do not worry about problems you don't have yet, you already have to deal with the ones you already have :)

Comment: @Nathan: i was multi thread in java. https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java

Comment: @Stephen: thanks for your valuable inputs...I just gave my minimum requirement 100 api calls/min to avoid any perf issues..Currently i see i can get all the response with in 10 sec for 100 http calls. So going forward need to increase the load to 500 max (my req). Being not an expert want to check or ask if the combination of multi thread and ajax call can help me increasing my load provided server can handle 500 api properly. Fr om client side would like to implememt any better approach if possible

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you a reliable answer to that.  Too complicated.  Too many unknowns.